# Pandas flatten rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file that looks like

```
item1 value1 0
item1 value2 0
item1 value3 0
item2 value1 0
item1 value2 0
item1 value3 0
```

I'd like to get a pandas dataframe where I have each value as a column, and each item as a row.

E.g.

```
item | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4...
item1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | NaN
```

I know how to do it by iterating over the dataframe, but I thought there could be a way to avoid iteration (as that's anti-pattern) through groupby perhaps?

Comment: How are you deciding duplicates? For example what if you had `item1 value2 0` and `item1 value2 23`? What would the output value be for `item1` vs `value2`?

Comment: Great question - Ideally I'd plug in a lambda function as a decider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you look for is called pivoting in pandas nomenclature. Here is a link to [pandas-pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html) documentation.

You simply have to do this:

```py
 df.pivot(index="item", columns="value", values="zero_col")
```

Change the names according to your dataframe column names.

**Edit**

I tested it locally and at least in the general case seems to work. Although, as @tdy suggested some cleaning up after the pivot operation might be necessary to fit your use case.

A snippet:

```py
c = {"items": np.arange(5), "values": np.arange(5), "zero_cols": np.zeros(5)}
df = pd.DataFrame(c, columns=["items", "values", "zero_cols"])
df.pivot(index="items", columns="values", values="zero_cols")
```

Here is the result:

```py
values    0    1    2    3    4
items
0       0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1       NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2       NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN  NaN
3       NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0  NaN
4       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0.0
```

Comment: Did you test this locally? It doesn't work on my end. Error about duplicates.

Comment: I have edited the answer to add an example. That duplicates error seems strange, but since there were no data provided in the problem statement, I wonder how this error might have occurred.

Comment: Awesome! Appreciate it. Now I just need to fix the index/drop the hierarchy

Comment: @kalgoritmi Your sample data has all unique `item*` numbers, but the OP's sample data has a lot of dupes (`item1` appears 5 times). That's why there's a duplicate index error when pivoting with the OP's sample data. But in any case, it seems to be working for Mikohvil.

Comment: You are right! I would like to add that if my sample data had any duplicates, then there would be additional non-NaN elements outside of the main diagonal, had the duplicates been only in the index column.

Comment: This is extremely odd unless it's a versioning issue. Does this code not throw a `ValueError` for you? `df = pd.DataFrame({'item':['item1']*3, 'value':['value1','value2','value1'], 'zeros':0}); df.pivot(index='item', columns='value', values='zeros')`

Comment: Yes you are right, it's not a versioning issue, when `values`, acting as column after the pivot, are not unique a duplicates error is thrown. But if the duplicates are constrained only in the `items` then it might work by using MultiIndexing.